# PDO query in foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I would like to do something like this but it is not working, I mean no elements are returned i.e. empty query. How could i achieve that?

```
foreach ($ghasharr as $key=>$val)
{
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(id) as ccount FROM pics WHERE gallery=:ghash");
$stmt->bindValue(":ghash", $key);
$results = $stmt->execute();
$countarr[$results['ccount']] = $results['ccount'];
}
```

Comment: its never be a good idea to query in loop

Comment: but i want to fill the `$countarr[]` array with the data returned by the query

Comment: It would be better to fetch all of the counts in one pass using a `GROUP BY` operator: `SELECT gallery, COUNT(id) AS ccount FROM pics WHERE gallery IN (?) GROUP BY gallery`

Comment: @tadman could you provide me an example of what do you mean exactly please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **`PDOStatement::execute`**
>
> Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure.

I.e. your `$results` is not an array. You want to fetch the results using one of the `fetch` methods of the `$stmt`. You also don't have to prepare the statement over and over:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT COUNT(id) as ccount FROM pics WHERE gallery = :ghash');
$stmt->bindParam(':ghash', $key);

foreach (array_keys($ghasharr) as $key) {
    $stmt->execute();
    $results = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $countarr[$results['ccount']] = $results['ccount'];
}
```

Comment: okay but i need the ghasharr value to append to query
AND like this is it still returning nothing
`$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(id) as ccount FROM pics WHERE gallery=:ghash");
$stmt->bindValue(":ghash", $key);
$results = $stmt->fetch();`

Comment: You `prepare`, you `bind`, you `execute`, then you `fetch`. Don't leave out the `execute`.

Comment: okay inside the foreach loop that is working now i think

Comment: Yes. It'd be better if you just make *one* query with all the ids you're looking for, but whatever floats your boat...

Comment: okay solved now working thanks for all of your great help

Comment: See update for better use of *prepared* statements.

Comment: Yes thanks for that i have made it inside the foreach loop but i will rewrite it